# Escape characters in systemd ExecStart fail

Tags: systemd, jenkins, sed, cloud-init

I have the following snippet to extract a value from a jenkins server jnlp config file. It works out of the box in the terminal but not as a unit. I want a unit so I can put the value somewhere and use it as an environment variable. However I keep getting an escape sequence error. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175461/how-to-use-quote-and-dollarsign-with-systemd) which suggests I only need to worry about quotes and slashes, but I get the same result. Here is the `ExecStart` of the file with the sed included:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'curl -L -s -X GET http://10.x.x.x:8080/computer/name-of-executor/slave-agent.jnlp | sed \"s/.*<application-desc main-class=\"hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main\"><argument>\([a-z0-9]*\).*/\1/\" >> /etc/build_environment'
```

I have tried many combinations of escape characters to no avail. Additionally, I use an identical pattern to extract a value from metadata (using curl, piping, etc) and that works fine. Definitely confused on what is happening here

Comment: Why are you calling a shell and redirecting output to a file with `>>`? Get rid of the shell and make the appropriate settings in the systemd unit itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not very experienced with systemd. I have another unit to write from a file, but this was the only way I found that works allow me to curl and output to a file.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=

Comment: Ugh I did not read far enough in the docs clearly. This makes sense I will try this tomorrow thank you.

Comment: I've been using systemd for close to nine years now, so I know most of it inside and out by now. I don't expect most people will though. There's a lot there.

Comment: I suspect I may see the same problem since the `>>` isn't the broken part of this snippet however. Or would I be able to skirt some escape issue by doing `ExecStart=/bin/sh...` instead?

Comment: You'll be able to skirt some escaping issue by not calling the shell at all.

Comment: Apologies but, clearly I have a huge gap in knowledge. I am interpreting the above link as using that directive to output the result of `ExecStart` into the file `StandardOutput` has defined. As this function depends on curl to get the file, and sed to extract the value, where can I call those except the shell?

Comment: Oh wait, you're actually piping here. I missed that bit. You're probably best off writing a shell script and calling that from the systemd unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to debug this is to add option `-v` to the `sh -c` in order to see what systemd is actually passing it.
If we do this we can see we are getting (reduced for readability):

```
curl ... | sed "s/... main-class="hudson...">.../\1/" >>...
```

The syntax error is that the double-quoted command given to sed has inside it `"` instead of `\"`.
This is because systemd replaces `\"` by `"` indiscriminately in the `ExecStart` string.

You need to pass a backslash to `sh` by using `\\` (which systemd will reduce to `\`), then the double-quote:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -cv 'curl... | sed "s/...main-class=\\"hudson...
```